# Yii events: set event as last

Tags: events, yii

I have several events handler (they are `CActiveRecordBehavior` classes) answering to the `onAfterSave` event of my `CActiveRecord` classes.

One of those events handler need that the others have been called to proceed.

How could I force this event to be the last executed?

My behaviors are declared as follow:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array_merge(
        array(
            'firstBehavior' => array(
                'class' => 'application.components.firstBehavior',
            ),
            'secondBehavior' => array(
                'class' => 'application.components.secondBehavior',
            ),
        ), parent::behaviors()
    );
}
```

I know that when I'm calling

```
$model->getEventHandlers($eventName)->add($eventHandler);
```

The event is append at the end of the list and executed last, but I don't now where I could put this code: 
- The `init()` method of activeRecord object is called before attaching the behaviors so the added event won't be the last executed even if I add it from this method and not by adding the behavior in the list.

Comment: It sounds like attaching an event handler is the wrong idea here. Perhaps overriding a method would be a better way to guarantee that your code runs exactly when you want it to?

Comment: The only method that I could override would be the "save" mehod by calling something like parent::save(); in it and then do my work. is this something acceptable?

Comment: More than acceptable, it's as natural as a baby's smile.

Comment: Ok thanks! In general I avoid to override the framework methods, I don't know why (except the ones that need to be overrided like the events, relations, ...)!

Comment: You shouldn't. I override them "all the time". If that's what it takes to clearly and unambiguously transfer your intent to code then that's what you do.

Answer (score 0):

AS Jon sais in the comments the best way to achieve it is not to attach an event handler bu to override an existing method:

```
public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null)
{
    if(parent::save($runValidation, $attributes)) {
        //Handle my event since the other events have been executed
        // in the parent::save method
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```